# Spacy code snippet runs "In [1]:" as expected, but any subsequent runs throw an error

Tags: python, spyder, spacy

I have started to learn [spaCy](https://spacy.io/), and I run into a problem that I've never encountered before right from the start. Starting with a very basic script, everything works as expected in the first run, but the same script throws an error in any subsequent runs. If I restart the kernel in Spyder, the script will run in [1] as expected.

I would like to figure out / fix what's causing this. It will slow down my learning if I have to restart the kernel each time, and I don't want to find other symptoms of whatever is wrong down the line.

I'm not a python wiz by any means, so for what it's worth, I haven't seen this before. I spent a significant amount of time googling and didn't find similar issues.

I posted to the r/spacynlp page – one user suggested that I try python 3 instead of 2.7. This changed the error message, but the behavior remains.

The errors (below) don't seem to be indicative of an actual problem with the code.

At first I thought it was my code, so I grabbed the code sample from the spaCy website, and the behavior is the same. Perhaps it's a problem with my system or a missing package (Linux mint 19.1, Spyder 3.2.6). I tried on another computer – same result, but it's the same OS and Spyder version.

Here's my code:

```
import spacy
ruzie = open("ruzie.txt", "r").read()
nlp = spacy.load("nl_core_news_sm")
ruzie = nlp(ruzie)
for token in ruzie:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_)
```

If I run in python 2.7, the error is "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'literal_eval'." In 3.6, I get "PicklingError: Could not pickle object as excessively deep recursion required." In both cases, the problem line seems to be "nlp = spacy.load("nl_core_news_sm")". I tried one of the English packages too, with the same result.

Edit: ugh, solved with a spyder upgrade :/

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please update to our latest version (3.3.6) and try again. Your problem should be fixed in that version.

Comment: Thanks, I did this yesterday and it worked briefly, but then I broke my whole system and had to start with a fresh install. Very briefly, I have Spyder (for python2.7) and Spyder3 (for python3.6). I upgraded spyder3 and that seemed to fix the problem there, but all the stuff I wanted to use with spacy is in 2.7, so I tried to upgrade spyder too. That got me an uncompatible IPython version and several other undesirable side effect. Whatever I did trying to revert that broke the whole system (couldn't boot into my desktop environment), so a said f*** it and started with a fresh install.

Comment: And after the reinstall things are also working for Python 2?

Comment: After fresh OS install, I reinstalled spyder and spyder3 as before (pip install). I set up a virtual environment for python3.6, and spacy works from there as expected. This is on spyder 3.2.6. Honestly, I'm a bit afraid to upgrade it – I don't really understand how it works, upgrading via pip in the virtual environment. I see spyder listed in the env pip list but it's not callable from the env, and any other way I can see to open it, it seems to be the same spyder as in global pip3 list. If you have advice in this regard (despite the "pip @ your own risk" warning), I'll take it. @CarlosCordoba

Comment: re: python 2, still same behavior as in the original post. I have a feeling this might be one of those reasons to just use anaconda.

Comment: Ah, I wrote "After fresh OS install, I reinstalled spyder and spyder3 as before (pip install)." but this is inaccurate. I used the software manager in Mint, which is why I have outdated versions. Maybe that (apt) overrides the version installed with pip somehow. ...I'll make a virtualenv for 2.7 and see if that works.